# I want to know how to arrive at the inward components as $T \sin(d\theta /2)$?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

The following is an example from David Morin's Introduction to Classical Mechanics.

A rope wraps an angle $\theta$ around a
pole. You grab one end and pull with a tension $T_0$. The other end is attached to a large
object, say, a boat. If the coefficient of static friction between the rope and the pole
is $\mu$, what is the largest force the rope can exert on the boat, if the rope is not to slip
around the pole?

*Solution*
Consider a small piece of the rope that subtends an angle $d\theta$. Let the
tension in this piece be $T$ (which varies slightly over the small length). As shown in
the figure, the pole exerts a small outward normal force, $Nd\theta$ , on the piece. This normal
force exists to balance the “inward” components of the tensions at the ends. These
inward components have magnitude $T \sin(d\theta/2)$. Therefore, $Nd\theta
= 2T \sin(d\theta/2)$.
The solution then continues to calculate the inequality $T\leq T_0e^{\mu\theta}$.

[image]
I do not know how to get the magnitude for the inward components as $T sin(d\theta/2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Since the axial action $T$ is aligned with the axis of the rope at every point, and since the infinitesimal element of the rope describe a arc of circumference of angle $d \theta$, the angle between the directions of the axial action $T$ at the free ends of the elementary rope is $d \theta$.

Now, draw the bisector of angle $d \theta$. This is your radial direction. The projection of each $T$ along this direction is $T \sin(d\theta/2)$.

Comment: Is $T$ not in the tangential direction to the rope or along the direction of the rope around the pole? By axial action, do you mean $T$ is along the direction of the pole?

Comment: $T$ is along the direction of the rope, but this direction changes, since the rope is rolled up around the pole.

Comment: as an example, in your picture the rope describes a small arc of a circle of angle $d \theta$

Comment: To confirm I'm getting it right, should I use the theorem that the angle between the tangents and the angles subtended by the radii of the arc are supplementary? where the tangents would be $T$ and angle subtended by the radii would be $d\theta$

Comment: Or that the angle between the two directions indicated by the 2 arrows T, is the same as $d \theta$